# Double binding in both services angular

Tags: angular

I have two services, Service1 and Service2, construstors of my services you see below:

```
// service1.service.ts
constructor(
    private service2: Service2
)

// service2.service.ts
constructor(
    private service1: Service1
)
```

but, when I compile it, I have been getting error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Service1' before initialization

I don't register any service in my app.module. What I can do?

Comment: And why do you do it? What do you want to acheive?

Comment: @Timothy I want transer data between services

Comment: This is completely illogical, you are importing service 1 in service 2 and service 2 in service 1. This will create circular dependency

Comment: Btw why do you want to do this? you can import one service in another and still accomplish what you want to achieve

Comment: @Kenny yes your're right, but, I know one deciding, inicialize references by using thid service, which will have two variables service1 and service2,

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/forwardRef

Comment: @Timothy can you make out it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First. As an option you can use [forwardRef](https://angular.io/api/core/forwardRef)

> Allows to refer to references which are not yet defined.

```
class SecondService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => FirstService)) private firstService: FirstService
  )
}
```

Second. You can use third common injectable singleton service which is used to host  / share common data (preferable way)